# when accessing my mastodon website, I get webpage of blocking domain

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, ubuntu-20.04, mastodon

i think it's a rails 6 problem, i added my domain to enviroment as it said, but it doesn't fix the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you have to add this in your `config/environments/production.rb` file:

```rb
# inside this block
Rails.application.configure do


  # existing stuff

  config.hosts << 'mikamistudio.com' 

end
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed, it turns out that I entered wrong domain name on setup. I should enter mikamistudio.com, however, I entered mg.mikamistudio.com. after change it, all things go well.
and also refer to the website that gives me a hint to solve the problem. the application need to rebuilt to apply changes on domain access.
https://linuxtut.com/what-to-do-when-blocked-host-host-name-appears-in-ruby-on-rails-7d729/
thanks!